# Do something just after symfony2 login success and before redirect?

Tags: events, authentication, symfony, hook

I'm searching for a while now, for any info, on how to do something after authentication success in symfony2. I want to rehash user password to use bcrypt just after successful authentication using old hash. I need to do this when I still have valid plain password so it should be just after credentials check and before redirect.

Any clues how to achieve that?

I found something about event dispatcher in Symfony but I <strike>can't find if there is any event after successful authentication.</strike>

Please correct me if I'm trying to do this wrong way and suggest some better approach.

//**EDIT**

Ok I found event fired just after auth success, it's called `security.authentication.success`. So i can now attach to this event but now I'm not sure where in my boundle code should I attach my event listener? Should I do that in my `/src/Pkr/BlogUserBundle/DependencyInjection/PkrBlogUserExtension.php` in `load()` method?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can specify a login success handler to be executed on successful login.

For example, your security.yml

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            success_handler: my.security.login_handler
```

Now create the class which implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` and on successful login, you can do whatever you need and handle the redirect as you see fit.

```
/**
 * 
 */
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    // handle it and return a response
}
```

Then create a service with that name in your services.xml for your bundle, or in your config.yml using the newly created handler.

I originally found out how to do this following this tutorial:

http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/

Comment: Great, I'll try it shortly :)

Comment: Your solution works great. At first I tried with event listener attached to login success event but then I didn't have request object so easy accessible as in your solution :) Thank you for help

Comment: When I tried this I found $request->headers->get('referer') was set to my login page.  Any idea how to get the page requested *before* the user was redirected to the login page?

Comment: You could try to edit the login controller and maybe set the referrer on that screen in the session and then access it and clean up in your login handler.

Comment: How would one access the session or the doctrine from within such a login success handler?

Comment: Since this is a service, you would use dependency injection to inject whatever other services you require in your constructor or setter method. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html

Comment: Since Symfony 2.8 there is a `Guard` authenticator service which aims to simplify creating custom authentication system. There is `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method which can return `RedirectResponse` but also can contain some custom logic . It's worth a look if building custom authentication process. Tutorial here http://www.sitepoint.com/easier-authentication-with-guard-in-symfony-3/