# How to Redirect out of an Event?

Tags: symfony

I am listening to security.authentication.success event. Everytime a customer logs in i need to check if he still got main information. If not, then i want to redirect him to the form for creation. It is running good but in which way can i redirect out of an event? Simply returning an Redirect Object does not work.

#### Service:

```
applypie_userbundle.newuser_listener:
  class: Applypie\Bundle\UserBundle\EventListener\NewUserListener
  arguments: [@router]
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.success, method: onLogin }
```

#### Listener:

```
namespace Applypie\Bundle\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class NewUserListener
{
    protected $context;
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router  = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @param AuthenticationEvent $event
     *
     * if current user neither have an applicant row or an company row, redirect him to create applicant row
     */
    public function onLogin(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {

        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if(!$user->getApplicant() && !count($user->getCompanies()))
        {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('applypie_user_applicant_create'));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908856/do-something-just-after-symfony2-login-success-and-before-redirect

Comment: this does not solve my problem.. i ve got the correct event but i dont know how to modify the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To cut the long story short, yes, you are listening to the correct event but... is someone waiting your method return?... NOPE!**

I can't test this right now, but this is the idea:

**security.yml**

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            success_handler: my.security.login_handler
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    my.security.login_handler:
        class:  Applypie\Bundle\UserBundle\EventListener\NewUserListener
        arguments:  [@router]
```

**NewUserListener**

```
namespace Applypie\Bundle\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class NewUserListener implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    protected function getResponse($name)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate($name);
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

        return $response;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        $route = 'user_home';

        if(!$user->getApplicant() && empty($user->getCompanies())) {

            $route = 'applypie_user_applicant_create';

        }

        return $this->getResponse($route);
    }
}
```

Sources:

http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface.html

[Do something just after symfony2 login success and before redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908856/do-something-just-after-symfony2-login-success-and-before-redirect)