# Symfony Security: Redirect to another language after login

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using form authentication in a Symfony full-stack application.

When a path is only accessible for registered users, the firewall will prompt for credentials and redirect to the originally requested URL afterwards (default behaviour).

In my application users can configure their preferred language in the profile. After login, the user should be redirected to the original URL, but in the preferred language. So ideally I'd like to modify the target path on authentication success to that the same route as the original request is used, but potentially in another language.

I already built an event listener listening on security.interactive_login, but there I can only build static paths as no route information is available.
Also it is not possible to save the original route when the firewall redirects to the login page, as the firewall is called before routing. So I think it's not possible to retrieve the route - or did I miss anything?

I can think of hacky solutions, but maybe someone can help with a better idea - thanks!

Comment: You can use an authentication success handler where you can implement your own logic there,
i think this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908856/do-something-just-after-symfony2-login-success-and-before-redirect) may help you

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm missing is not an opportunity to react to authentication but the name and parameters of the route to redirect.

Comment: how are you managing language preference for users ?

Comment: Just providing a profile page where the language can be selected from a dropdown. The language ISO code is then saved in a user record in the database from where it is then read on login and can be used where needed. After login there will be a language switch so that the user may change languages manually, so the preferred language won't affect anything after login.